# com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error

Tags: netflix-zuul, hystrix

I want to run a multiple number of concurrent requests through the Zuul gateway using Eureka servers.

When doing this, I faced this Error Internal server error 500. Any solution or suggestion to solve this are welcome.

```
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: YYYYY could not acquire a semaphore for execution and no fallback available.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not acquire a semaphore for execution
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to increase the executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests from your hystrix configuration, like this:

```
    public HystrixCommandInstance() {
      super(Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("SomeGroupName"))
      .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
             .withExecutionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests(200)));}
```